# El uso de "cómo que/aunque" en una respuesta a una oración de alguien

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras

En varias películas ví el uso idiomático de "cómo + que" o "cómo + aunque" en unas respuesta a unas oración de alguien.

De "Wind River" (película de Hollywood traducida a español):

*-Vivía en Fort Wakashie. Algo al Norte.*

*-¿**Cómo que** algo?*

*-**Como** a 30 minutos en coche.*

De "El Aura" (Argentina):

*-Está todo bien, aunque no venga*

*-¿**Cómo aunque** no venga?*

De "El Contratiempo" (España):

*-Virginia está aquí porque puede que la fiscalía se nos haya adelantado.*

*-¿**Cómo que** la fiscalía?*

De "La Víctima Número Ocho" (España):

*-No.*

*-¿**Cómo que** no?*

Preguntas:

1. ¿Cómo usar esta estructura? ¿En cuáles circunstancias se puede usar?
2. ¿Podría en el caso de "Contratiempo" responder: "***Cómo que** la fiscalía se nos haya adelantado*"? ¿O esta estructura aplica solo a una o dos palabras, como en los ejemplos mencionados? Supongo que se puede responder con varias palabras consecutivas, pero responder como en los ejemplos mencionados sería más conveniente.

P.S. Por adelantado les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores  si hay algunos, o en gramática o en uso de palabras o en algo más.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La expresión "cómo (que)" en preguntas se usa para cuestionar lo que el interlocutor está diciendo, o para pedirle aclaración. Es similar al inglés *how come.*

En general se usa "que", como si dijerámos "¿Por qué dices **que** ...? Veamos ejemplos:

- Vive lejos.
- ¿**Cómo que** lejos?
- Vive solo.
- ¿**Cómo que** solo?
- Vive aunque sufra.
- ¿**Cómo que** aunque sufra?
- Vive donde sabes.
- ¿**Cómo que** donde yo sé?
- Vive como puede.
- ¿**Cómo que** como puede?
- Vive si tiene un motivo.
- ¿**Cómo que** si tiene un motivo?
- Vive con un amigo.
- ¿**Cómo que** con un amigo?

Si se omite "que", se hace una pausa, que en la escritura puede reflejarse a través de una coma, como si dijéramos "¿Por qué dices **:** ...? En este caso, lo que sigue a "cómo" podría ir entre comillas, porque sería un extracto del discurso directo.

Comment: Por lo general, entiendo. Al pensar como sería una traducción al inglés, pienso en primer lugar en "what you mean [by saying this...]?". Sería correcto este significado?

Comment: Ambos significados son posibles.

Comment: Alex, ref. tu comentario, deberías decir "en general", no "por lo general", en este caso.

Comment: Entendido. Si no te importa aclarar, ¿que es la diferencia entre "en general" vs "por lo general"? Es que siempre pensaba en que los dos son sinonimos con el mismo significado

Comment: Tanto "en general" como "por lo general" pueden usarse para frecuencia, pero sólo "en general" se usa para referirse al grado o medida, en este caso de entendimiento. Si quieres, puedes formular una pregunta específica al respecto así puedo explayarme un poco más.

Comment: Creo que tengo entendido :)