# El uso de "que" en circunstancias específicas

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras

Encontré el idiomático uso de "que" en varias películas abajo. Pero no pudé agruparlos y categorizarlos bajo algún único significado. También puedo añadir que ya pregunté varias veces sobre el uso idiomático de "que" y en estas preguntas creo que sí logré agrupar y categorizar el uso de "que":

[El uso de "cómo que/aunque" en una respuesta a una oración de alguien](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35268/23475)

[El uso de "que" para hacer una pregunta otra vez o precisar una pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35269/23475)

[El uso de "que + no" o "que + sí" durante unas circunstancias emocionantes al responder a alguien](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35277/23475)

[Es uso de "sí + que" al contestar a alguien](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35278/23475)

Y aunque esta vez no puedo agrupar los ejemplos abajo en esta pregunta, habrá algo en común con el uso de "que" en mis preguntas anteriores. Por lo menos, a mi parecer.

De "La Víctima Número Ocho" (España):

*-Me has mandado unas tarjetas de embarque que están mal.*

*-Un momento, **que** lo miro.*

Un ejemplo más de "La Víctima Número Ocho":

*¿Qué haces **que** me miras así?*

De "El Desconocido" España:

*Ahora calladitos, **que** tengo que hacer una llamada*

Un ejemplo más de "El Desconocido":

*-Haces el favor de mover el coche?*

*-Que sí, **que** ya lo muevo!*

De un video de BBC Mundo sobre las mascarillas (en 3:45) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkdL3esx7t0:

*Ojo, **que** ningún estudio científico de los que encontramos dice que el uso de esta pantalla debe ser la única medida!*

Preguntas:

1. ¿Por qué fue usado "que" es estas oraciones?
2. ¿Sería gramaticalmente incorrecto no usar "que" en estos ejemplos? ¿O "que" es imprescindible aquí?

P.S. Por adelantado les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores si hay algunos, o en gramática o en uso de palabras o en algo más.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En todas las oraciones mencionadas "que", que no está acenduado, no es pronombre relativo (no se refiere a ningún sustantivo), por lo que sólo puede ser **conjunción**.

En [esta página](http://elvelerodigital.com/apuntes/lyl/que.htm) puede encontrarse un muy buen resumen de los distintos usos o valores de la conjunción "que". Veamos:

> 4.- Conjunción
>
> 4.1.- Coordinante:
>
> - copulativa: Obras son amores, **que** no buenas razones. (= y)
> - disyuntiva: Quieras **que** no, ...  (= o)
> - adversativa: Ha sido niño, **que** no niña. (= No ha sido niña, sino niño)
>
> 4.2.- Subordinante:
>
> 4.2.1.- Conjunción anunciativa (introduce proposiciones subordinadas sustantivas)
>
> Quiero **que** lo veas. (subord. sustantiva de CD)
>
> 4.2.2.- Distintas conjunciones que funcionan como nexo introductor de proposiciones subordinadas adverbiales:
>
> - causal: No corras, **que** te vas a caer. (= porque)
> - comparativa: (introduce el segundo elemento de la comparación):
>
> Ir con él es mejor **que** quedarse en casa.
>
> - consecutiva: Estudia tanto **que** va a enfermar.
> - final: Sal, **que** te dé el sol. (= para que)
>
> - Hay otros muchos casos en los que aparece formando parte de locuciones conjuntivas : temporal (antes que), consecutiva (así que), final (para que), causal (ya que), concesiva (a pesar de que), condicional (a condición de que), etc.
>
> 5.- “Que” incoloro
>
> Muchas veces, el “que“ es innecesario. Se introduce en el discurso como elemento expresivo, identificador o de refuerzo, pero no aporta un valor sintáctico o relacionante propiamente dicho. Es frecuente en el habla coloquial. Puede tener distintos matices:
>
> - Valor exhortativo : **Que** te calles.
> - Valor narrativo: **Que** de noche lo mataron al caballero, la gala de Medina, la flor de Olmedo. / **Que** me ha dicho Juan que...
> - Valor desiderativo: **Que** llueva, **que** llueva...
> - **Que** te crees tú eso.
> - Esta sí **que** es buena.
> - **Que** sí, hombre, **que** sí.   (refuerza la afirmación)
> - **Que** te van a dar.  (advertencia)

Veamos ahora qué valor puede atribuirse a cada uno de los "que" que aparecen en las oraciones citadas:

- Un momento, **que** lo miro. (En este caso estoy indeciso entre el valor causal y final: *Un momento para que lo mire* o *Un momento porque quiero/necesito mirarlo*.)
- ¿Qué haces **que** me miras así? (Tampoco en este caso me queda claro si estamos en presencia de una conjunción subordinante final = *¿Qué haces para mirarme así?* o causal = *¿Qué haces por mirarme así?*)
- Ahora calladitos, **que** tengo que hacer una llamada. (Claramente en este caso se trata de una conjunción subordinante causal = ***porque** tengo que hacer una llamada*)
- **Que** sí, **que** ya lo muevo! (Para mí, éste sería un caso de un *dummy* "que" -- vacío o incoloro, como dice el autor de la página de referencia.)
- Ojo, **que** ningún estudio científico de los que encontramos dice que el uso de esta pantalla debe ser la única medida. (También sería conjunción subordinante causal, ya que explica por qué el oyente o el lector debe tener cuidado, o sea, el porqué de la alerta.)

Comment: En la sección 5 - tengo entendido correcto si los "que" no son gramaticalmente necesarios en estos ejemplos allí? ¿Tal cómo fue en https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35269/23475 ?

Comment: Sólo sería necesario en el segundo caso: *¿Qué haces **que** me miras así?*